# How to remove fields from the admin user create page of Sonata User Bundle?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle, symfony-2.6

I have installed [Sonata Admin Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin) and [User Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user) in my Symfony 2.6 application. I found that the User bundle creates a bundle at `src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle`. When I go to the admin user creation page (`admin/sonata/user/user/create`), I found a lot of fields there:

- General

  - Username
  - E-Mail-Address
  - Plain password
- Groups
- Profile

  - Date of birth
  - Firstname
  - Lastname
  - Website
  - Biography
  - Gender
  - Locale
  - Timezone
  - Phone
- Social

  - Facebook Uid
  - Facebook Name
  - Twitter Uid
  - Twitter Name
  - Google+ Uid
  - Google+ Name
- Management

  - Roles
  - Locked
  - Expired
  - Enabled
  - Credentails expired
- Security

  - Token
  - Two Step Verification Code

I only need Username, E-Mail, Password, Groups, Firstname and Lastname for my admin user creation. How can I remove the other unnecessary fields from that page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under configuration for sonata user bundle in `config.yml` i.e `sonata_user` you can override sonata user admin class and define your own admin class

```
sonata_user
    admin:                  # Admin Classes
        user:
            class:          Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
            #Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
            controller:     ApplicationSonataUserBundle:UserCURD /** you can also override CURD controller for your admin class*/
            translation:    SonataUserBundle
```

Now create your user admin class in your extended bundle i.e `ApplicationSonataUserBundle` and extend your class with sonata's `Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin`, now in `configureFormFields()` define your desired fields you want to add

```
use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin;
class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin {
    protected function configureFormFields( FormMapper $formMapper ) {
     $formMapper->add('some field'); ...
     /** Do your stuff here */
    }
}
```

Or remove some of the fields :

```
use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin;
class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin {
    protected function configureFormFields( FormMapper $formMapper ) {
        parent::configureFormFields($formMapper);
        $formMapper->remove('some field');
    }
}
```

See [`ADVANCED CONFIGURATION`](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) for sonata user bundle