# Override Users Form Sonata UserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

Hello I tried to follow the explanation given here:

[How to remove fields from the admin user create page of Sonata User Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690298/how-to-remove-fields-from-the-admin-user-create-page-of-sonata-user-bundle)

To add / remove lines to the Sonata Userbundle registration form but the problem is that I find myself for this error: [image]

Here are the few lines of code that I put: 
in src/Application/Sonata/userBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php

```
use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin {
    protected function configureFormFields( FormMapper $formMapper ) {
        parent::configureFormFields($formMapper);
        $formMapper
            ->remove('facebookUid');
    }
}
```

In 
app/config/config.php :

```
sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm
    admin:                  # Admin Classes
            user:
                class:          Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
                controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
```

Can someone tell me why? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to declare the namespace of your UserAdmin class.
It has to be the very first line of code, and will be like that in your case:

```
<?php
namespace UserBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin {
```

Comment: Yeah i find the issue a week ago i odn't know how i can forget it ^^' but thx